# my listview was empty

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview using `CustomAdapter`. first, i try to display my listvew with ArrayAdapter and all item seems good. but when i try to change them with custom adapter all item was gone. here is my arraylist

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getAllAssignment() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> daftarAssignment = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select customer.name from assignment, customer where"+
    " assignment.customerid=customer.customerid and employeeid = '"+Globals.salesid+"'", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            map1 = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
            name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NAME));
            map1.put("one",String.valueOf(daftarAssignment.size()));
            map1.put("two",name);
           daftarAssignment.add(map1);  
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return daftarAssignment;
  }
```

here is my adapter

```
ListAssignment= dataSource.getAllAssignment();
adapter = new CustomAdapter(ListAssignment.this, ListAssignment, R.layout.item_list,
                new String[] {"two"},
                new int[] {R.id.edtype});
```

and my `CustomAdapter()`

```
package ims.app.mobileorder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{
    private int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#3BB9FF"), Color.parseColor("#306EFF") };  
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mylist, int itemTo,  
            String[] from, int[] to) {  
    super(context, mylist, itemTo, from, to);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: show your adapter code

Comment: first try to print list size after calling getAllAssignment() method using Log class.

Comment: Check getCount mush return data.size() / data.length

Comment: Check the size of daftarAssignment.size(); and the show me how to call the CustomAdapter function. So i can provide the exact solution.

Comment: where are you call this **ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> ListAssignment = getAllAssignment();**?

Comment: Can you show code of your CustomAdapter?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ i've show my adapter

Comment: @Imtiyaz i'll try your advice

Comment: @PiyushGupta on my public class

Comment: @Imtiyaz i've try to calling getAllAssignment() method using Log,all value is appear

Answer (score 0):

Your CustomAdapter should look like this :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.data=data;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map = data.get(position);
        long id = Long.valueOf(map.get(KEY_ID));

        return id;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if(convertView==null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
        TextView message = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_message);

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map = data.get(position);

        title.setText(map.get(KEY_TITLE));
        message.setText(map.get(KEY_MESSAGE));

        return view;
    }
}
```

And when adding an item on the activity :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(CustomAdapter.KEY_ID, String.valueOf(i));
map.put(CustomAdapter.KEY_TITLE, "Title " + i);
map.put(CustomAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE, "Message " + i);
data.add(map);
}

mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, data);
mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dip"
>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textStyle="italic"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where should i get values from sqlite